# pseudo elements not showing on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tabspanel content container for jquery tabs to which i'm trying to apply an advanced box-shadow using pseudo elements. However, the pseudo elements aren't showing for some reason.

CSS

```
#about-us .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  display: table;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 0px 30px 80px 30px;
  background: #5643ce;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about-us .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 52px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  box-shadow: 7px 6px 15px #333;
}
#about-us .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 52px;
  right: 5px;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  box-shadow: -7px 6px 15px #333;
}
```

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#about-us .tab.inner" ).parent().addClass( "tabs-container" );
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  event: "mouseover"
});
$('#tabs a, kill-a-action').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
} else {
}
}).resize();
$("#select-loader").fadeOut();
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#tabs-wrapper").fadeIn();
}, 1000);
});
```

Wonder what the problem could be -- normal box-shadow is working fine. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the pseudo-elements as `block`s instead of `inline-block`s, and give them `width` and `height`, since they otherwise would remain as "large" as their content, which is `""`..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your pseudoelements some dimensions (height and width) for them to show up; otherwise they will just fit to the content, which in your case is blank. I suspect since it looks like you're using them to create a framing effect, you'll also want to position them absolutely so that they don't "push" your content down.

Finally, you'll want to be careful not to end up hiding them due to the 'overflow hidden' on your container... I'm not sure exactly what effect you're looking for, but tinkering around with it, I ended up with something like this:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 0px 30px 80px 30px;
  background: #5643ce;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel:before {
  content: "";
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  box-shadow: 7px 6px 15px #333;
}
```

See codepen example: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/QqjrvB

Comment: thanks for this.. for some reason the pseudo element is showing but is positioned at the top of the page rather than on the div. I suspect this is because the tabs are being created dynamically and so take a second to style correctly. Is there any way to delay the pseudo element until the tabs is completely rendered?

Comment: You need to make sure the element has position: relative so that the absolute positioning will be relative to it, otherwise it will be relative to the first ancestor it finds of position relative (or absolute), which may be the page

Answer (score 0):

In your case "display: table" is the culprit. I am unaware of why you have used display table but i am sure there are many better ways to get your desired output, be it vertically centre alignment or layouts etc without using display table property.
Usage of table in layouts is sensitive topic, but here i am not cursing tables in anyway. You can have a look at https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero to understand better.
One has to be very careful using display table as it often leads to many unexpected behaviour and we often end up applying hacks for our desired output. Css flex works like a charm and has the potential to entirely replace tables and can even help you here as well if you are willing to disregard IE8 and IE9.